# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o- JSON.Parse

Tags: javascript, json

I use openexchangerates api to get exchange rates value. What is wrong wih var t = JSON.parse(json.rates);?
I get 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o' 
To check

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {

        var t = JSON.parse(json.rates);
         console.log(t);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: When you console.log(json), what do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to parse anything with `JSON.parse`. Error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

means that `json.rates` is already an object you can use. And it makes sense because this is how JSONP works: some function is executed behind the scene and some javascript object is passed in it.